# Executing "db2look" in VB Excel - Getting Run-Time error: An unexpected "db2look" was found

Tags: vb.net, excel, db2, db2-luw, vba

I am trying to execute "db2look" command from within Excel using VB. But I'm getting Run-time Error
An unexpected token "db2look" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT". Expected tokens include: "DECLARE". SQLSTATE=42601

I know connection and everything is fine, as I am able to run simple select queries and based on error it's not connection issue but rather like "db2look" not recognized or valid. I've ran same exact command in cmd window at it works fine.

Just wondering if anyone has been able to run the "db2look" command outside of db2 command window/editor and using VB/Excel? Or if there is something that I am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[db2look](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/c0020703.html) is a tool and standalone executable which cannot be run like a regular SQL statement. It needs to be run from the command line (shell).

Comment: thanks. yes, so my approach now is to create.bat file from within my vb as well as execute the .bat file, which will contain the db2look commands and create files.